# Await find mongodb not working in electron

Tags: node.js, mongodb, electron

I am developing an app with nodejs, express and electron, everything is perfect when executing npm run from the vs code terminal, the problem is when I generate the executable with electron-builder, the routes that have queries to mongodb stop working, they stay loading infinitely without showing the render, it stops right at the line that makes the query to mongobd

it's my code

```
router.get('/games',  async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let page = req.query.page || 1;
        const stylegames='show';
        const games = await  Games.paginate({}, { limit: 8, page: page, sort: { name: "asc" } }); 
        res.render('games/all-games',  { games, stylegames });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

    }
});
```

I appreciate any help in advance

Comment: it means mongoose is not connected,. share snippet that has `mongoose.connect....` line

Comment: `const mongoose= require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT, {
    
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true 

})
.then(db=>console.log('DB conectada'))
.catch(err=>console.log(err));`

Comment: in development mode it works

Comment: do you have the env file in the same folder as your binary? If you are generating binary you may as well just use const var for your DB_CONNECT

Comment: mongoose should have shown error, check your logs (note: once you start server, it takes about [10sec](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#callback_never_executes) to throw error, so wait for it)